# How do I generate the sprite randomly on x coordinate

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have this piece of code but when I put `randomno` in place of the x co-ordinate it gives an error.

Here I want the position of x co-ordinate to be random.

```
func createmonsters()
    {
         randomno = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1) \\creating a random number
        monster=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monster")
        monster.size=CGSize(width: 60, height: 70)
        monster.position = CGPoint(x :self.frame.width/2, y:self.frame.height)
        self.addChild(monster)
        monster.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

         monster.runAction(moveandremove)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting the error about `randomno` in `monster.position.x` is because it expects a `CGFloat` not an `int`.

```
   let randomno = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1)
   monster.position = CGPointMake(randomno, 100)
```

---

Just an FYI, the `randomno` variable is only going to return the numbers 4, 3, 2 & 1. You might want to make that number larger if you're interested in a bigger `x` position, maybe `self.frame.width`.

Comment: func createmonsters()
    {
        let randomno = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(180) + 1)
        monster.position = CGPointMake(randomno, 100)
        monster.size=CGSize(width: 60, height: 70)
        
      
        monster.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
       
        
          self.addChild(monster)  \\giving error here                                                   
       
         monster.runAction(moveandremove)
    }

Comment: Do you have a runAction `moveandremove` sounds like you don't and that's why you are getting the error. Remove that line and the error will disappear.

Comment: yes i have... and it was working b4 i put the random number and giving self.frame.width/2 as x coordinate

Comment: can you add the `moveandremove` function/variable to your original question. I don't know what that is, so I can't help until I see that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183420/swift-2-showing-error-thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-adress-0x0